# Am I using the boolean operator wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boolean-expression

I'm trying to look in a array to see if a precise element (x) is found in it.
For this I'm saying at the beginning of the problem that contor=0 (boolean parameter), meaning that there is no x in the array, but if while the for loop is runing and x is found in the array, i said that contor=1 ... and at the end i did the test if(contor) else and it's not working in the case when x is not found in the array. It's just not showing anything. I don't get it ...I'm a beginner. Thank you!

```
  #include<iostream>

  using namespace std;

  void main()

  {int x, st, dr, m,n,i,contor=0;       //dr = right, st = left, m=middle;
   int v[100];

   cout << "How many elements will the array have?";
   cin >> n;
   cout << endl;

   for (i = 0; i < n;i++)
      {cout << "Insert a element in the array:";
       cin >> v[i];
      }

   cout << "Which is the number you are looking for?";
   cin >> x;

   st = 0;
   dr = n - 1;

   for (i = st; i <= dr;)

      {m = (st + dr) / 2;

      if (v[m] == x)
         { contor = 1;
            break;
         }
      else if (v[m] > x)
          dr = m - 1;
      else st = m + 1;
      }

   if (contor)
       cout << "The element you are looking for is in the array.";
   else
       cout << "The element you are looking for is NOT in the array.";

   cin.get();
   cin.get();
   }
```

Comment: It is vital that you format your code consistently with indentation if you wish us to spend more than five seconds reading it.

Comment: i thought it was all right from the beginning the indentation. I did some changes now. Is it all right ?

Comment: No. Still inconsistent. I suggest reviewing [this wikipedia article on indent styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)...

Comment: I will. But i really don't think it has a bad indentation. You know there are quite a lot of styles of indentations ...

Comment: Notice how after `void main()` (which should be `int main(void)`, btw) you've not increased indentation, yet after `for (i = 0; i < n;i++)` you have. Also notice how after `for (i = 0; i < n;i++)` you've not indented beyond the `{` (e.g. there are no spaces after that) yet after `if (v[m] == x)` (which needs an extra space to be consistently indented) you have. Notice how `m = (st + dr) / 2;` and `if (v[m] == x)` fall onto different tabstops, as do `contor = 1;` and `break;`... They're not aligned. Do you still think this is consistent? It's an improvement, at least...

Comment: Yet I think you have seen much worse indentations (not a missing space or two in three places) and you checked the code more than five seconds ... It means a lot to have good measures and to not exaggerate. I wrote that I am a beginner in programming ... patience ... there were more comments on this question and nobody said nothing about the indentations ... if they would have been so bad, the guys would have said something. But I appreciate your observations ...a little bit more kindness i expect.

Comment: Nobody is being unkind here; you don't see abusive language, do you? I might have spent more than five seconds analysing your code, but nonetheless I don't think that's an exaggeration; I think other people would have stopped analysing quickly. Perhaps if I hadn't mentioned it, someone else might have?

Comment: @R.I.P.Seb `int main` yes, but the `void` in the argument list is a C-ism that has no place in C++.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Note the edit at the same time as your comment where the C tag was removed... Additionally, I'm no C++ expert but if the void notation is described in a C++ standard, doesn't that mean the central authority which decides what constitutes C++ has decided that there is a place for it in C++?

Comment: @R.I.P.Seb  ok, didn't notice the edit. But the place for this in C++ is C compatibility.

Comment: @SebastianRedl yep, and the C++ standard seems to defer to the C standard for main entry points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do a binary search, but you do it inside an infinite cycle. If the element is found, you break from the cycle, but if it is not found, your cycle continues endlessly. Also, you try to do a binary search in an array which is not guaranteed to be ordered. Assuming that the array is ordered, which means that:

> i <= j <=> v[i] <= v[j]

this is what could work:

```
do {
    m = (st + dr) / 2;
    if (v[m] == x) {
        contor = 1;
        break;
    } else if (v[m] > x) {
        dr = (st + m - 1) / 2;
    } else {
        st = (m + dr + 1) / 2;
    }
} while (st < dr);
```

Comment: I tested also when the array has only one element and x is different than the element of the array (bigger or smaller) and it works just fine. (for Lajos Arpad's last comment in the answer scored with -1 that was erased).We had a disscusion there.

Comment: so i just had to erase the st=0, dr=n-1 and put this conditions in the for (st = 0, dr = n - 1; st <= dr;) and it's working properly for all the tests that i did.(and yes, the array is ordered.)